# Stringtemplate with dollar sign

Tags: java, stringtemplate

What is the best way to deal with dollar sign in stringtemplate.

For example I need following template:

```
You can purchase item $name$ for $5
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried escaping the $?

```
You can purchase item $name$ for \$5
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use escaping, for example `\$`